# How to display JSON results in web page?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get Json results from my API to be displayed in the #jsondata in my html, but nothing seems to be working.

HTML:

```
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="form" action="/hotels" method="GET">
        <!-- location search bar -->
        <input
          class="form-control mr-sm-2"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search Location"
          aria-label="Search"
          id="searchbar"
          name="name"
        >
        <!-- end of location search bar-->

        <!-- start of location search button -->
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="searchbutton">
          Search
        </button>
        <!-- end of location search button-->
      </form>
      <!-- end of form -->

      <!-- start of map -->
      <div id="map"></div>
      <!-- end of map -->

      <!-- start of search result placeholder box-->
      <div class="scrolling-box">
        <div class="hotels">
          <p id="jsondata"> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
var Amadeus = require('amadeus');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.listen(8080);

app.get('/hotels', function(req, res){
    amadeus.shopping.hotelOffers.get({
        cityCode: 'PAR'
    }).then(function(response){
      res.send(response);

    //var jsonData = JSON.parse(response.body);
    //res.render('data', {jsonData: jsonData});

    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error.response); //=> The response object with (un)parsed data
      console.log(error.response.request); //=> The details of the request made
      console.log(error.code); //=> A unique error code to identify the type of error
    });
});
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchbutton').submit(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get('/hotels', function(data){
            $('#jsondata').html(data);
        })
        return false;
    });
)};
```

I think I get that the "action="/hotels" method="GET"" part of my form in the html means that the "/hotels" path will be called straight away after the search button is pressed, and so the javascript won't run? But if i remove it the javascript doesn't seem to be running either?
Sorry if this makes no sense, it doesn't make much sense in my head either

Comment: the same way you added `console.log` statements in your backend, add some in the EJS file, and see if you are hitting the function first, then if the `$.get()` actually returns anything at all... plus, try to go to the `/hotel` route in your browser to see if you get data, and let us know your findings

Comment: Please share what $.get is getting

Comment: $.get isn't returning anything , when i go to the /hotel route though i get the json data, just not where i want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML ,add a onclick trigger for the search button :

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="form">
            <!-- location search bar -->
            <input
              class="form-control mr-sm-2"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search Location"
              aria-label="Search"
              id="searchbar"
              name="name"
            >
            <!-- end of location search bar-->

            <!-- start of location search button -->
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="searchbutton" onclick="getHotels()">
              Search
            </button>
            <!-- end of location search button-->
          </form>
          <!-- end of form -->

          <!-- start of map -->
          <div id="map"></div>
          <!-- end of map -->

          <!-- start of search result placeholder box-->
          <div class="scrolling-box">
            <div class="hotels">
              <p id="jsondata"> </p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And in your script, use it like below :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getHotels(){
        $.get('/hotels', function(data){
            $('#jsondata').html(data);
        })
        return false;
    };
)};
```